# Getting Error : error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException status code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am attempting a project in Udacity's AWS Cloud Architect Nanodegree program. And am writing the code to deploy an AWS Lambda Function using Terraform. I believe I am supposed to use `greet_lambda.py` as the lambda function to be deployed through terraform. File is mentioned below and so far have executed the below steps:

greet_lambda.py

```
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "{} from Lambda!".format(os.environ['greeting'])
```

Zipped the lambda file:

```
$zip ../greet_lambda.zip greet_lambda.py
```

Created a bucket in S3:

```
$aws s3api create-bucket --bucket=dirai-terraform-lambda --region=us-east-1
```

Uploaded the zip file into S3:

```
$aws s3 cp greet_lambda.zip s3://dirai-terraform-lambda/v1.0.0/greet_lambda.zip
```

main.tf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-1"
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
    name = "lambda_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
   function_name = "greet_lambda"
   s3_bucket = "dirai-terraform-lambda"
   s3_key    = "v1.0.0/greet_lambda.zip"
   handler = "greet_lambda.lambda_handler"
   runtime = "python3.7"
   role = "aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn" 
}
```

And I get the below error on $terraform apply:

```
Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException: 
    status code: 400, request id: e6289eb7-40f5-4cf2-ba0a-e8b5ae656466

  on main.tf line 33, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda":
  33: resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
```

Please help me here what I could be doing wrong. The lambda is successfully exported into S3. But the terraform apply is failing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `role` will be **literal string** `"aws_iam_role.greet_lambda.arn"`.
It should be (no quotes):

```
role = aws_iam_role.greet_lambda.arn
```

Comment: Based on subsequent question edit, should be: `aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn`

Comment: @BrentBradburn Yes, but not in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes role should be correct but in my case, I added lengthy lambda description and was causing issue. It should be not big.